# How to display successively 2 objects on the same frame on beamer

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

Is it possible to display a paragraph on a template then immediately hidding it and displaying another paragraph at its place.
I don't know how to do it because in my case I would like to display an equation and then display a paragraph (which implies hiding the equation on the template and displaying the paragraph like if the equation has never been there).

I didn't find any hint to do it, I have only encountered the \itemize option but this is not what I aim to do.

Sorry if it's a bit unclear and thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{onlyenv}<1>
    \[E=mc^{2}\]
  \end{onlyenv}
  \begin{onlyenv}<2->
    content...
  \end{onlyenv}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is the tool that I was looking for

Comment: @Wiss At some point, you might want to have a look at the beameruserguide - it does have a tutorial at the start.

Comment: Yes I did ! As I said in my post, I've found a lot of tools that are used for overlays (For instance, \temporal was close to what I was looking for) but I didn't encounter the \onlyenv explanation. Of course, you can learn a lot of other techniques but practicing it is quite complicated IMO (Usually, I don't use beamer)